# Redirect to another page in WPF on certain conditions

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi i am making a WPF application.

I have a mainwindow, which i have my navigation in, then i also have a stackpanel, with this:

```
<Frame x:Name="_mainFrame" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden"/>
```

inside, where i place my pages inside.

In My mainwindow i navigate to other pages using the following to for example move to the gameWindow:

```
private void NavigateGameWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _mainFrame.Navigate(new GameWindow());
        }
```

This works fine, but now that i am inside that window (gameWindow), i am checking if a "player" is set, if not, i want to navigate to another page, where i can set certain values.
and then navigate back to GameWindow.

But how do i get a hold of _mainFrame, when it is a part of the mainwindow ?

It says in GameWindow on _mainFrame

```
The name _mainFrame, does not exist in the current context
```

**Game Window**

```
public partial class GameWindow 
{
    private int numberOfPlayers;
    private Player[] players;

    private INavigator _navigator;

    public GameWindow(INavigator navigator)
    {

        _navigator = navigator; //assign navigator so i can navigate _mainframe to other pages.

        // initialize game properties, check if they are set.
        var gameProp = new GameProperties();
        this.numberOfPlayers = 2;

        this.players = gameProp.CheckPlayerIsSet(this.players);
        //check if a player has been set
        if (this.players != null)
        { // Player is set or has been set. proceed or start the game.
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        else
        {   // redirect to settings window because players has not been set!
            _navigator.Navigate(new GameSettings());
        }
    }
}
```

**Main Window**

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window, INavigator
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ExitGame(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }

    public void Navigate(Page p)
    {
        _mainFrame.Navigate(p);
    }

    private void NavigateRulesWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Navigate(new GameRulesWindow());
    }

    private void NavigateGameWindow(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Navigate(new GameWindow(this));
    }
}
```

**GameSettings**

```
 public partial class GameSettings : Page
{
    public GameSettings()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //var gameProps = new GameProperties();

        // set number of players,, should prompt user, and get value!
        //gameProps.SetNumberOfPlayers(2);
    }
}
```

**View for gamesettings**

```
<Page x:Class="ITD.OOP_Projekt.WPF.Menu.GameSettings"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ITD.OOP_Projekt.WPF.Menu"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
      Title="GameSettings">

    <Grid Background="white">
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="229,144,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="This is game settings" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Comment: Where are you getting this error? I mean which part of code?

Comment: you should proper and important code blocks, here no one can understand exact issue you got.

Comment: I asked that share the all required code blocks. where you are getting The name _mainFrame, does not exist in the current context this error

Comment: @GaurangDave when i try to use the same code as the navigategamewindow, with the _mainframe, that is where it says that.

Comment: I think someone should at least mention that this approach is unusual. MVVM is the de facto standard for WPF and I recommend you consider it.  One simple way to do navigation is to use viewmodel first. Also.  Pages are rarely used by anyone but beginners in wpf apps. Contentcontrol and usercontrol would be much more usual for this.

Comment: i am absolutely a beginner. And i only have a week to get this working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One very easy solution is this:

So with the following code you have only one Window (Mainwindow) and inside that Window you display your pages. You can compare it with your internet browser. You have one window and inside that window you can navigate between pages (settings, game, highscore, ...).
I hope this helps and you can get it to work!
If not i can try to upload a simple example to github in the evening.
Just get rid of your GameWindow and implement it as a page.

**MainWindow**

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="PageSwitcher.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PageSwitcher"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>

  <Frame x:Name="MainFrame" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" />

</Grid>
```

cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : INavigator
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Navigate( new Page1(this) );
    }

    public void Navigate( Page p )
    {
        MainFrame.Navigate( p );
    }
}
```

**Page1**

xaml:

```
<Page x:Class="PageSwitcher.Page1"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PageSwitcher"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
  Title="Page1">

<Grid Background="Green">
  <Button Width="150" Height="30" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Content="Go to Page2" /> 
</Grid>
```

cs:

```
public partial class Page1 : Page
{

    private INavigator _navigator;

    public Page1(INavigator navigator)
    {
        _navigator = navigator;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
    {
        _navigator.Navigate(new Page2(_navigator));
    }
}
```

**Page2**

xaml:

```
<Page x:Class="PageSwitcher.Page2"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PageSwitcher"
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
  Title="Page2">

<Grid Background="Blue">
    <Button Width="150" Height="30" Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" Content="Go to Page1"/> 
</Grid>
```

cs:

```
public partial class Page2 : Page
{
    private INavigator _navigator;

    public Page2(INavigator navigator)
    {
        _navigator = navigator;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
    {
        _navigator.Navigate(new Page1(_navigator  ));
    }
}
```

Thats all you really need.
In this example you can switch between two pages on button click events.
Just start a new wpf project and copy the code.
Play around with it until you understand it and then try to implement it in your game :)

Comment: so far this looks awesome with the interface, i am just going to try an implement it, then see if it works. I will set this to answered if it works.

Comment: can you post your new code?
Your GameWindow class and MainWindow please.
I´ll try to help you:)
Just edit your question

Comment: Added the code, and the new window gamesettings i am trying to show

Comment: also added the view, not much on it, just some text for now

Comment: Ill post a complete sample project

Comment: marking it as answer, because i think it is more me that does not know how to properly make it work. I believe your stuff works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect the page from one page to another you can create one method or function in which you can write the conditions and use the below code for redirection. It will take care of the directory also.

**NavigationService.Navigate(new Settings.LatestActiveUsers());**